# Intersection of non-transverse manifolds

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, transversality

> Suppose that $X$ and $Z$ do not intersect transversally in $Y$. May
>   $X\cap Z$ still be a manifold? If so, must its codimension still be
>   $\operatorname{codim}X+\operatorname{codim}Z$? (Can it be?)

Is my solution correct?

An example I have in mind is $Y=\mathbb R^2$, $X=x$-axis, $Z=\{(x,y):y=x^2\}$. Then $X\cap Z=\{(0,0)\}$, $X$ is not transverse to $Z$, but a one-point set is a manifold. Its codimension is $2$, which equals $\operatorname{codim} X+\operatorname{codim} Z$. So the answer to the first and third question is yes.

The answer to the second question is no: Consider two orthogonal axes in $\mathbb R^3$. Each of them has codimension $2$, but their intersection has codimension $3$.

Comment: seems fine to me

Comment: A more extreme example of a nontransverse intersection is the one of the x-axis and the x-axis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property of non-transversal manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949888/property-of-non-transversal-manifold)

Comment: Why did you consider codim$(X)+$codim$(Y)$?

Comment: @Convex this is a typo, I meant $\operatorname{codim} X+\operatorname{codim} Z$.

Comment: Ok so isn’t codim $X+$ codim $Z=4$?

Comment: In my notation, $X$ is a line and $Z$ is a parabola, both in $\mathbb R^2$. Each of them has dimension (and hence codimension) $1$.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, I was thinking of $\mathbb{R^3}$.